# iPhone- Avoid video compression in UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

In my app , im uploading videos to server. Im using the native `UIImagePickercontroller` to pick the videos from the gallery.

The delegate i have is ;

```
imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

My application has to work in the background and while picking large videos from gallery the compressing time is so annoyingly high that , the user some how gets irritated and exits the app.While this occur, the `beginbackgroundTaskWithExpirationhandler` gives me 10 mins for `bgTask`.But if the compression process is in excess of 10 mins while app is in background the OS suspends /kills my app.

Do you have any idea how I can avoid this.??

Comment: You cannot avoid the 10 minute limit. You should display a progress bar, or let the user know on some other way that the app is working on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, there is no way to avoid compression completely. Setting the video quality to high should help though.

`myController.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;`

**EDIT:** I have not tested this, but it sounds like it would work. It's a remake of the UIImagePickerController that claims to give raw access to images and videos.

GitHub: https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController

More info about it: http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/07/cloning-uiimagepickercontroller-using-the-assets-library-framework/

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to acquire a PHAsset object, use this instead of a third-party solution (finer control, never have to upgrade):

```
[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:phAsset options:nil resultHandler:^(AVAsset *avAsset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *info) {
    NSURL *url = (NSURL *)[[(AVURLAsset *)avAsset URL] fileReferenceURL];
    NSLog(@"url = %@", [url absoluteString]);
    NSLog(@"url = %@", [url relativePath]);
 }];
```

Whereas phAsset is the PHAsset object, and avAsset is the resulting AVAsset object generated by PHImageManager, the output to the console from the above code will produce, for example:

```
2016-04-16 01:15:40.155 ChromaEpsilon[3423:933358] url = file:///.file/id=16777218.8262005
2016-04-16 01:15:40.155 ChromaEpsilon[3423:933358] url = /private/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/108APPLE/IMG_8421.MOV
```

There's more than just these two, I believe, but start here.